# Using Xamarin Forms, maintain aspect ratio of Navigation Page Title Icon in Landscape on iPhone X

Tags: xamarin.forms, aspect-ratio, iphone-x

When running a Xamarin Forms app that uses a TitleIcon on a Navigation Page, the image is squished when the device is turned to landscape mode.  What do I need to do to maintain the aspect ratio of the image as it does with previous devices?

iPhone 8 Portrait:

[image: iPhone 8 Portrait]

iPhone 8 Landscape:

[image: iPhone 8 Landscape]

iPhone X Portrait:

[image: iPhone X Portrait]

iPhone X Landscape:

[image: iPhone X Landscape]

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of customizations, I think you might be better off avoiding the built in NavigationPage NavigationBar and instead implement your own navigationbar in XAML. It would be relatively simple to just use a grid or absolutelayout with your desired background color and image and place it at the top of your pages. You could use a control template or a reusable content view to avoid copying and pasting the bar to every page. Once you've got that done you just have to hide the default navigationbar by using

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(myPage, false);
```

Or by adding this to the top of your content page definition in XAML

```
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
```

Something like this might help you get started:

http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2017/january/replacing-the-xamarin-headernavigation-bar-with-a-custom-viewtemplate/